# Sum across multiple columns and variable row

Tags: excel, vba, variables, sum, row

I need the sum from every row for column F to column P. After a lot of errors I finally have it like this: see code, now it doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't work; when I go through the code with f8 I see that it stays zero, even though the row sum is not zero in the sheet.

```
dim i as integer
For i = 2 To numrows
som = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Reservationsheet.Cells(i, 6), Reservationsheet.Cells(i, 15))

I've already tried:
som = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Range(Cells((i), "F"):((i), "P"))) &
som = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Range(Cells(("F" & i):( "P", i))) 'etc, but here i get error messages

Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Reservationsheet.Cells(i, 6), Reservationsheet.Cells(i, 15))
```

is like writing on the worksheet:  `SUM(Fn,On)`.  In other words, you are only adding two cells.

To add the range, you need to specify the entire range with something like:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Reservationsheet.Cells(i, 6), Reservationsheet.Cells(i, 15)))
```

And the `Sum` function will return 0 if your numbers are really the text representations of numbers, and not real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here a few ways of accomplishing that:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 2 To numrows
    With Reservationsheet
        Dim v As Variant
        'v = .Evaluate("SUM(F" & i & ":P" & i & ")")
        'v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.Intersect(Rows(i), .Range("F:P")))
        v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(i, "F"), .Cells(i, "P")))
    End With
```

Some are faster than others, some are more readable and adaptable for your scenarios...

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Across

**Short Answer**

```
    som = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ReservationSheet _
      .Range(ReservationSheet.Cells(i, 6), ReservationSheet.Cells(i, 16)))
```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumAcrossUseful()
    Dim ReservationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim som As Double

    Set ReservationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reservation")

    LastRow = 5
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        som = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ReservationSheet _
          .Range(ReservationSheet.Cells(i, 6), ReservationSheet.Cells(i, 16)))
        Debug.Print som
    Next i

End Sub

Sub SumAcrossMoreUseful()

    Const SheetName As String = "Reservation"
    Const FirstCol As Long = 6 ' "F"
    Const LastCol As Long = 16 ' "P"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim som As Double
    Dim tot As Double

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    LastRow = 5
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, FirstCol), ws.Cells(i, LastCol))
        som = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.Value)
        Debug.Print "Sum   = " & som
        tot = tot + som
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Total = " & tot

End Sub
```